# C++ A certain date input will display a selected line of text

Tags: c++, date

I'm still new to C++, but I want to write C++ program that lets the user input a date and then a few lines of text will appear displaying events from what happened on that day in the past. The exact year is not needed. It takes the inputed number and searches through a numbered list and then displays the message. I want something like:

```
Insert a date: 15
On this day: Stack Overflow reached 500

Insert a date: 34
I'm sorry "34" is not a valid date.
Please insert a valid day.

Insert a date: 1 4 18
On this day: Daylight savings ends
On this day: The World Is Not Enough hits theaters.
On this day: Facebook was created
```

Comment: Well, what did you try so far ? And where shall the events come from ?

Comment: I haven't tried out anything yet. This is more like a hypothetical thought. I'm still new to C++. I want the events to come from an embed list in the C++ file.

Comment: A simple solution could use `std::map<DateType, std::vector<EventType>>`

Comment: Ok. I'd recommend that you read the events from a [text file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/).  The date is to be understood as a day within the current month ?

Comment: Text file, got it. Yes, the date would be a day within the current month.